# How to hide my waiting screen when In app purchase UIAlertView is show?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase

I've added an UIAlertView that has UIActivityIndicatior as a subview on my application. This alertView only show when the purchase is in progress. How to hide my waiting screen when In app purchase UIAlertView is show?

[image: In app purchase UIAlertView]

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                [self stillPurchasing]; // this show a waiting screen
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                NSLog(@"2");
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                 NSLog(@"4");
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"5");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it will be more useful if you keep it until the purchase operation is fully completed .. thats mean in case 1 (SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased) you hide the indicatore ,, also dont forget to hide it in case the purchase failed.